# Problem with org-element-property and math formulas in Org 9.0.9

Tags: org-mode

With Org 9.0.9, I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of `(org-element-property :contents-end (org-element-context))` in items that end with a math formula (`^` being the position of the cursor):

```
- $bla$ ^
```

yields `non-nil`, as expected, but

```
- $bla$^
```

yields `nil`, as if the item was empty. This doesn't change even when I move the cursor inside the formula. Just the whitespace after the formula seems to make a difference.

Bug or feature?